# for (var i = 0; i &lt; count; i++) { } == for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { }. What is this notation and why use it?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, scripting

Ran into the notation:

`for (var i = 0; i &lt; count; i++) { }`

on [this tutorial](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/). I gather it is equivalent to:

```
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) { }
```

What is this notation? Why use it? Does it perform better?

Comment: It is a bug in the web page (i.e. they meant to say `<`). `&lt;` is HTML speak for `<`. Also, https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ .

Comment: the `&lt;` is equal to `<`. That is just the html encoding for the `<` character. The character probably just didn't get properly encoded on the website you were looking at. 
That is called a "for-loop" function which you use to iterate through a collection, for example an array.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp  This link will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an HTML parsing error. `&lt;` is supposed to show up as `<`. You're right - it's supposed to be `i < count`.